# Redirecionar via COOKIE

Tags: php, redirecionamento

Olá !

Meu cliente precisa que o usuário seja redirecionado para a página onde ele estava acessando antes de finalizar a sessão anterior. Por exemplo:

Usuário Acessou -> Página A (CRIOU O COOKIE)

Usuário encerrou a sessão.

Quando o usuário retornar ao site, ele deve ser redirecionado exatamente pra página onde ele estava anteriormente, ou seja, página A.

Alguma sugestão? Obrigado!

Comment: Seria legal postar já o que tentou fazer, e qual a dificuldade que encontrou, e especificar melhor a estrutura do site e em que condições é pra acontecer o redirecionamento. Se for só pra ter um "palpite" de como fazer, acho que além de ficar fora do escopo do site, e pra piorar acaba dependendo da opinião de cada um. Por exemplo, o que acontece se a pessoa entrar por um link pra determinada página? Quando a pessoa quiser voltar pra home, como faz? (e assim por diante, explicando com clareza como é pra funcionar)

Answer (score 2):

Em todas as páginas que terão esse recurso, você deve adicionar um comando para gravar a URI no cookie, assim:

```
setcookie('client_uri', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], (time() + (30 * 24 * 3600)));
```

O comando acima irá guardar a URI atual num cookie chamado client_uri que terá validade de 30 dias.

Para redirecionar o usuário para a página que ele estava, faça isso:

```
header("Location: //{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_COOKIE['client_uri']}");
```

E agora você tem um problema, porque somente o código acima irá fazer um loop de redirecionamentos, então: como saber se o usuário já estava no site ou se ele acabou de chegar? Afinal, eu só preciso redirecioná-lo se ele tiver acabado de chegar.

A princípio usar as `sessions` do PHP parece ser uma solução, porque elas são destruidas quando o navegador é fechado (a menos que o cliente use a opção de continuar de onde parou nas configurações do navegador), mas tem um outro problema: e se ele apenas fechar a aba e voltar pro site? A session ainda vai estar lá e ele não será redirecionado para a página que estava anteriormente.

A solução mais simples que eu consigo pensar seria usar o `HTTP_REFERER` do PHP. Então o código completo ficaria assim:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['client_uri']) && !empty($_COOKIE['client_uri'])) {
        header("Location: //{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_COOKIE['client_uri']}");
    } else {
        setcookie('client_uri', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], (time() + (30 * 24 * 3600)));
    }
} else {
    setcookie('client_uri', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], (time() + (30 * 24 * 3600)));
}
```

O código acima funciona da seguinte maneira: se o usuário chegou até a página através de uma referência (links apontando pro seu site, independente de esses links serem internos ou externos), ele apenas seta a nova URI no cookie chamado `client_uri`. Se ele chegou no site e não veio de nenhuma referência, ele verifica se existe um cookie chamado client_uri e, se existir, redireciona o usuário para a URI gravada no cookie, se não existir, então mantem o usuário na página e cria um cookie chamado client_uri.

É a solução mais simples que consigo pensar e você poderia fazer isso de várias outras maneiras, algumas até mais eficientes, porém com um pouco mais de engenhosidade (complicação). Essa **não** é a melhor maneira de fazer o que você quer, afinal, tem problemas que inclusive o Bacco deixou em comentário na sua pergunta: e se o cara saiu do site e quando ele voltar, ele quiser ir pra URL principal e não pra onde ele estava quando saiu? Tem também o problema da variável `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` que alguns navegadores podem não enviar ou enviar com alguma manipulação.

Enfim, acredito que com isso você já tenha alguma base para começar desenvolver da maneira que mais se adeque as suas necessidades.

Comment: A resposta é boa, mas eu acho arriscado demais responder sem o autor esclarecer alguns pontos antes. Levou meu +1 pelo cuidado de explicar os problemas principais (além de usar o location: corretamente, com o nome completo).

Comment: você é um gênio amigo! vou tentar dessa maneira e te dou um feedback... +1